# Return types of urllib geturl() change

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, encoding, urllib

On Python2

For some reason geturl() sometimes returns unicode, and other times returns strings. I want to encode it to unicode, but it is failing as I dont know the encoding of the string or even if it is unicode.

Any suggestions?

Comment: what is your input to geturl when a string and when a unicode comes out?

Comment: `url.decode('ascii') if not isinstance(url, unicode) else url`